# Laravel orWhere but always where status is 1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$teachers = Teacher::where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orWhere('father', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orWhere('phone', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orWhere('job_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->where('status', 1)
                ->latest()
                ->paginate(50);
```

I want to get orWhere-s with always where status is 1. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `where` clause and can add you each condition without status condition like that:

```
$teachers = Teacher::where(function($query) use ($q){
                $query->where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                      ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                      ->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                      ->orWhere('father', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                      ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                      ->orWhere('phone', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                      ->orWhere('job_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
            })
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(50);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
$teachers = Teacher::where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->orWhere(function($query) {
            $query->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                  ->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                  ->orWhere('father', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                  ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                  ->orWhere('phone', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                  ->orWhere('job_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
             })
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(50);
```